# When Text in Table is long, other table shape is distorted

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, text-size

What I want is when the text is long, the table shape should not be distorted. As seen in the image I added, the 1st text is long, other cells and texts are corrupted. I want to fix this.

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="30dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:background="#f1f1f1"
        >

        <TableRow>
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="fospfdmglfdmglğpkdsağgorjgdfglkdfdsfsdfsdfg"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tel"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
```

[image]

Comment: How do you want it to behave?

Comment: If the text is long, the text may shrink or slide down without disrupting the cell. As long as it doesn't disturb the order of the cells, the whole image is distorted because of 1 cell

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code, I changed layout_width and it is working fine.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="30dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:background="#f1f1f1">


    <TableRow>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="fospfdmglfssssssssssssssssdfglkdfdsfsdfsdfg"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Email"

                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"/>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tel"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>



    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I did not understand what to check, it is not working properly, I asked for help to fix this anyway?

Comment: I mean please try this code, I already fixed the weight issue.

Comment: thank you lastly, how can I make the e-mail and wire part the same size as the 1ststun?

Comment: Sorry, Didn't get you.

Comment: The sections in the name of e-mail and tel that you sent were small, I want the first part to be bigger and all the same size and not to overflow when you write.

Comment: You can change weight for 3 text views to match your requirements

Comment: I do but it may not fit when switching to a different phone. It looks different on every phone.

Comment: please check code again, I have updated it , using weight will work fine with different phones ,please mark it as correct answer so anyone else can use it if he faced the same problem.